# Iotdb docker standalone not starting

Tags: docker, apache-iotdb

I would like to test out iotdb. However, I can't get it to start...

Here is the docker-compose (copy pasted from the website) :

```yaml
# docker-compose-standalone.yml
version: "3"
services:
  iotdb-service:
    image: apache/iotdb:1.3.0-standalone
    hostname: iotdb-service
    container_name: iotdb-service
    ports:
      - "6667:6667"
    environment:
      - cn_internal_address=iotdb-service
      - cn_internal_port=10710
      - cn_consensus_port=10720
      - cn_seed_config_node=iotdb-service:10710
      - dn_rpc_address=iotdb-service
      - dn_internal_address=iotdb-service
      - dn_rpc_port=6667
      - dn_mpp_data_exchange_port=10740
      - dn_schema_region_consensus_port=10750
      - dn_data_region_consensus_port=10760
      - dn_seed_config_node=iotdb-service:10710
    volumes:
        - ./data:/iotdb/data
        - ./logs:/iotdb/logs
    networks:
      iotdb:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.0.6

networks:
  iotdb:
    external: true
```

Here are the command I am doing :

```
docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=172.18.0.0/16 --gateway=172.18.0.1 iotdb
docker compose up
```

But here is what I get :

```
[+] Running 1/0
 ✔ Container iotdb-service  Created                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.1s 
Attaching to iotdb-service
iotdb-service  | update dn_internal_address /iotdb/conf/iotdb-datanode.properties
iotdb-service  | update dn_data_region_consensus_port /iotdb/conf/iotdb-datanode.properties
iotdb-service  | update cn_internal_port /iotdb/conf/iotdb-confignode.properties
iotdb-service  | update dn_rpc_address /iotdb/conf/iotdb-datanode.properties
iotdb-service  | update dn_mpp_data_exchange_port /iotdb/conf/iotdb-datanode.properties
iotdb-service  | update dn_rpc_port /iotdb/conf/iotdb-datanode.properties
iotdb-service  | update cn_consensus_port /iotdb/conf/iotdb-confignode.properties
iotdb-service  | update cn_seed_config_node /iotdb/conf/iotdb-confignode.properties
iotdb-service  | update cn_internal_address /iotdb/conf/iotdb-confignode.properties
iotdb-service  | update dn_schema_region_consensus_port /iotdb/conf/iotdb-datanode.properties
iotdb-service  | update dn_seed_config_node /iotdb/conf/iotdb-datanode.properties
iotdb-service  | Checking whether the ports are already occupied...
```

...Then nothing more happens. The cpu is at 100% and I see no other logs.

What could I try ?